# Is it possible to store in Redux a just new-made object posted to MongoDB and have access to its ObjectId without making a GET request

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, redux

I have a store made with Redux who stores locally an array of object. Also, this array is stored in a mongo database.

Since my application may not have access to internet at every moment, when I add one object to the array, I POST it to mongo and since it is asynchronous it will just work when my app will catch the network.

At the same time, I update my reducer, I just add the same object, not the one that I would GET from the mongodb database after update.

But then, my local array have the new object without the ObjectID generated by mongo. So if I need to access it later via his _id, I can't.

I can't afford making a new ID field, I really need the mongo one.

```
const newObject = {
        Name: 'name',
        Visible: true,
      };

let nextArray = [...oldArray, newObject];

this.props.dispatch({type:'ARRAY_UPDATE', value: nextArray});
        axios.post('http://localhost:4000/Array',nextArray )
```

Then my Redux array is [...oldArray, {Name:'name', Visible:true}]

While my mongo array is [...oldArray, { _id:ObjectId('5ca52869c8f23918407535b2'), Name:'name', Visible:true}]

It's inconvenient since I need the _id, working with the local array.

Would it be safe to generate myself an _id ?

If yes, then I'm pretty sure this library (https://www.npmjs.com/package/bson-objectid) would do the work, otherwise, is there a safer way ?

Thanks.

Comment: You can have the `ObjectId` in the browser. The [`bson`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bson) library works just fine there. You might also want to look at [`mongodb-extjson`](https://github.com/mongodb-js/mongodb-extjson) which actually follows the [MongoDB extended JSON](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/) specification for serializing/deserializing BSON type information into standard JSON formats. The latter used on your browser client and server API gives you a way to transport these types and then have the full type available within the client.

Comment: Bottom line is as the "primary key" you would run into problems if you attempt to "synchronize lists" with your browser client storage without the same information. You either end up creating a different "unique identifier" or basically enable your client to understand and use the `ObjectId` values. IMHO, the latter is the usually the most sane option.

Comment: I will check these out, thanks for the reply !